# Azure SSO configuration for Tomcat

Tags: azure, tomcat, web-applications, single-sign-on, saml

The SSO details of my application is configured on Azure side. I got metadata and Certificate. Now how to use this on the tomcat side. One of my web application is running on tomcat and this web application is protected using this SSO.

Comment: Typcially you use some SAML library / framework within your web application. That SAML library / framework may implement a SAML ServiceProvider which uses the meta data. It depends which library / framework you are using. Please provide that information.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. Yeah am looking for some good libraries for this. Will something like Picketlink work? Please suggest if you know something else which is easy to configure.

Comment: Yes, you could use Picketlink SP implemenetation. If you're using Spring, then you may look at Spring Security SAML extension.

Comment: The PicketLink has only support for JBOSS. Someone did for tomcat but that's bit old. Even on Spring SAML extention, that's a bit old as well. And with new one , it does n't look complete.

Comment: Nevertheless Spring Security SAML extension is one of the most complete SP implementation. PicketLink is used as a ServletFilter, hence it does not depend on a specific Servlet Container.